# How can I optimize Laravel Query between two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Here is my logic.

```
Table:  
pages:id,name
types:id,name
spots:id,page_id,type_id,name

Model:  
Page (hasMany Spot)
Type (hasMany Spot)
Spot (belongsTo Page and Type)

Controller:
$pages = Page::with("spots")->get();
$types = Type::with("spots")->get();

View:
@foreach($pages as $page)
    @foreach($types as $type)
        {{$page->name}} <br>
        {{$type->name}}  <br>
        {{Spot::wherePageId($page->id)->whereTypeId($type->id)->count()}}  // here is n+1 issue
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

How can I optimize query to display above view?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your relationships are already defined then you don't need to get Type::lastest() and Spot::latest(), just work with the relationship.

Comment: How can I do it? Relationship is already established well. Could you please show me some code? My biggest concern is to get count of spots. How can I do that without n+1 issue?

Comment: i dont understand the `pages x types` part ... but you can load relationship counts  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: `pages x types = @foreach(pages as page) @foreach(types as type) @endforeach @enforeach `

Comment: But you need both loops? If you have defined your page->type relationship then you don't need both @foreach loops. Just directly access the type with $page->type->name.

Comment: Well, there isn't relation between page and type. There are relation between page and spot, relation between type and page.

Answer (score -1):

You can using Laravel Eloquent Relationship.. You can read docs here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

In your "Sport" table add this function :

```
use (path to your 'type' model);
use (path to your 'pages' model);

example : use App\Models\Type;
    
public function RType(){return $this->belongsTo(Type::class,'type_id','id');}

public function RPages(){return $this->belongsTo(Pages::class,'page_id','id');}
```

in your Type Model :

```
use (path to sport model);

public function TSport(){return $this->hasMany(Sport::class,'type_id','id');}
```

in your Pages Model :

```
use (path to sport model);

public function PSport(){return $this->hasMany(Sport::class,'page_id','id');}
```

and in your view :

```
@foreach($data_sport as $val)
echo 'type = '.$val->RType->name;
echo 'pages = '.$val->RPages->name;
@endfoeach
```

Comment: well, i need to run foreach($pages as $page) foreach($types as $type)

Comment: not you dont. its automaticly show the relation of your child table with one query $foreach on your sport tabel. 
read carefully before you down vote the given aswer..